# Getting total (sum) of employees working under female managers - sqlite

Tags: sqlite, rdbms

I have a coondition where I should show all employees under female managers. So I wrote this query.

```
select count(E.emp_id) as EmployeeCount, M.name, M.gender   
from employee E Join employee M on M.emp_id = E.manager_id 
where M.gender ='Female' group by M.name, M.gender
```

Above query returns

```
4   Camila Wolstenholme Female
7   Clemmy Lamberts Female
9   Janot Saxon Female
3   Tina Fain   Female
```

But what I want is employees working under each female manager and sum of employees working under all female managers, i.e., 4+7+9+3=23.I want 23 to be shown along with employees working under each female manager. How can I do that

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query So please provide a tailored toy database in the shape of a few lines of `create table ....` and `insert ...`. Also provide the desired result for the provided toy database.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the following may do what you want :-

```
SELECT
  (SELECT count() FROM employee ee JOIN employee  mm ON mm.emp_id = ee.manager_id WHERE m.gender = 'Female' ) AS Total ,
    count(E.emp_id) as EmployeeCount, M.name, M.gender,
    group_concat(e.name) 
FROM employee AS E  
JOIN employee M on M.emp_id = E.manager_id 
WHERE M.gender ='Female' group by M.name, M.gender
```

## Example/Demo

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (emp_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT ,gender TEXT, manager_id INTEGER);
INSERT INTO employee (name,gender,manager_id) VALUES 
  ('Camila Wolstenholme', 'Female',null),
  ('Clemmy Lamberts','Female',null),
    ('Janot Saxon','Female',null),
  ('Tina Fain','Female',null),
  ('Fred Bloggs','Male',1),
    ('Anne Smith', 'Female',1),
    ('Sarah Thompson','Female',1),
    ('Trudy Mann','Female',1),
    ('Jane X','Female',2),
    ('Audrey Wood','Female',2),
    ('Mary Bartman','Female',2),
    ('Teresa Owens','Female',2),
    ('Amanda Jones','Female',2),
    ('Sophie Alexander','Female',2),
    ('Andrea Turner','Female',2),
    ('Jessica Walsh','Female',3),
    ('Suzy Quertermain','Female',3),
    ('Alanah Taylor','Female',3),
    ('Catherine Wilkinson','Female',3),
    ('Rose Dennis','Female',3),
    ('Debbie Waterford','Female',3),
    ('Elaine Bywaters','Female',3),
    ('Farah Flannagan','Female',3),
    ('Gina Heartman','Female',3),
    ('Helen Inglis','Female',4),
    ('Ingrid Sachs','Female',4),
    ('Julie Zimmerman','Female',4),
    ('Frank Smith','Male',null) /* Male Manager */
;

SELECT
  (SELECT count() FROM employee ee JOIN employee  mm ON mm.emp_id = ee.manager_id WHERE m.gender = 'Female' ) AS Total ,
    count(E.emp_id) as EmployeeCount, M.name, M.gender,
    group_concat(e.name) AS Manages
FROM employee AS E  
JOIN employee M on M.emp_id = E.manager_id 
WHERE M.gender ='Female' group by M.name, M.gender 
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee; /* Cleanup Environment */
```

## Result

[image]

- NULL has been used to indicate a Manager in the absence of an indication of what distinguishes a manager.

## Additional

> However showing total for each column could be confusing, is it possible to show it as a single row?

The following will show it as a single row with all other values. That is a) the total column is not extracted but instead a row is added via a UNION with the total in the first column and the other columns blanked out.

```
SELECT
  /* (SELECT count() FROM employee ee JOIN employee  mm ON mm.emp_id = ee.manager_id WHERE m.gender = 'Female' ) null AS Total ,*/
    count(E.emp_id) as EmployeeCount, M.name, M.gender,
    group_concat(e.name) AS Manages
FROM employee AS E  
JOIN employee M on M.emp_id = E.manager_id 
WHERE M.gender ='Female' group by M.name, M.gender 
UNION SELECT (SELECT count() FROM employee ee JOIN employee  mm ON mm.emp_id = ee.manager_id WHERE mm.gender = 'Female'),'','',''
;
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: This is good... However showing total for each column could be confusing, is it possible to show it as a single row?

Comment: @AjayKulkarni the answer has been amended.